# Should I nofollow and/or noindex links that are not cached?

Tags: seo, google, magento, nofollow, noindex

I have a Magento store with what they call a layered navigation. Basically a menu with links to things like color, price, etc.

I'm currently not caching these links, and so their response time is pretty low compared to all the category and product pages.

I'm wondering:

A) If Google crawls them and ranks them low due to their slow server response, will this pull my overall score down?

B) If A is true, what's the best way to prevent Google from crawling them?

Comment: It's difficult to say without actually seeing your website, but if those pages in the layered navigation aren't the only pages to reach your category and product pages, then you might nofollow them. Again, this is just a random advise without looking at your site

Comment: With all due respect, but I think you ask the wrong question. Are there any negative effects on having these links also be cached? If not, wouldn´t it be just better to just cache the pages in order to avoid possible negativ effects on the side of google (which is the end of your equation you cannot control and do not 100% know the answer to). Because then you can just stop guessing what google might or might not do and dont have to ceep track if it changes but just improve overall usability of your page and improve the loading times.

Comment: Well yes @veritaS, I use redis for my FPC and there's a limit to the memory  I can use for cache. I actually do cache them if they're clicked on, but I don't warm the cache because that would be too expensive since attribute links create many combinations of urls.

Comment: Have you identified the differences in loading speed? WHat is the over all loading speed? Maybe check it with the browser consol in IE

Comment: @veritaS I use siege or jmeter. I have different tools. What's the point of your question? It seems completely off track to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I nofollow and/or noindex links that are not cached?

At this point of time adding the nofollow to the anchor tags and the noindex to the non-cacheable links in your situation is a good idea.

What I would suggest is to evaluate the (what I believe to be) tiny pages that indicate features of the item such as color and price, and if they don't have enough content, merge the contents of those pages with the product page. No one wants to make an additional click just for the screen to turn blank for a moment and then have only one word or number show up on the screen.

If however you have a page giving long paragraphs about a feature (for example, describing how deep a red is and why that color is best for the product, etc), then let google index it and let the page be cache-able, then you will score a greater audience and better response times, plus you can make a link to that feature page from the product page.